# LESS mixin with parameters syntax error

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, less

I've got the following mixin that adjusts the width and padding of an item to cope with IE7's lack of support for box-sizing:border-box. It gives me a syntax on & .width(@width: 100, @paddinglr: 0)

I appreciate this is missing a % but any ideas why it's breaking?

```
.width(@width: 100, @paddinglr: 0) {
  width: @width;
  padding: @paddinglr;
}

body {
&.lt-ie8 {
    & .width(@width: 100, @paddinglr: 0) {
        width: @width-@paddinglr;
        padding: @paddinglr;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: For what it's worth, the `&` is redundant in that line.  The selector would be generated as `body.lt-ie8 .width` without the `&`.  LESS just might be a little more strict than Sass in how you're allowed to use the `&`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot define a mixin as a selector string, so `& .width()` for your nested portion cannot be a mixin definition (which is what you have tried to make it).

I think what you are trying to do is make a generic `.width()` mixin to use on any particular element. It appears that you intend to just set a single number for `padding`, which is fine.

***However***, it also appears that (based off your `%` comment), that you expect this code to produce a `width` value that is `100%` of the parent minus the value of the `padding`. This is okay, too, assuming you are using *percentages* for `padding` also. If you are not, but intend instead that the `padding` be a pixel value, *that mixed units cannot be done by LESS* as you might expect, as LESS is a *preprocessor*, so it is not dynamic in the sense of being able to detect the `width` of the parent based off the percent at run time and then subtract the `padding` pixel value.

Now, if your intentions are percentages, or any equal measurement values for *both* `width` and `padding` (whether both `px`, both `em` units, etc.), then you can get what you desire by various means. One of the many solutions would be by overriding the `.width()` mixin within the `.lt-ie8` nest, so for example:

```
.width(@width: 100%, @paddinglr: 0) {
  width: @width;
  padding: @paddinglr;
}

body {

.someDiv {
   .width(100%, 10%);
}

&.lt-ie8 {
    /* here is the override of the mixin */
    .width(@width: 100%, @paddinglr: 0) {
    /* note, I believe you will want to multiply the padding by 2 for the width change due to left and right padding */
        width: @width - (2 * @paddinglr);
        padding: @paddinglr;
    }
    /* and here is the override of the actual css */
    .someDiv {
        .width(100%, 10%);
    }
  }
}
```

Which produces this CSS (minus the comments above which were just to communicate to you):

```
body .someDiv {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10%;
}
body.lt-ie8 .someDiv {
  width: 80%;
  padding: 10%;
}
```